# ESTA re entry into USA

Tags: esta, repeat-visits

We travelled for 90 days  between July and Oct 2018.
Then Hawaii Dec 2018.
Can we come back to the States June to Sep 2019?

Comment: The question needs more specifics. Where were you traveling between July and Oct 2018? Why mention Hawaii, it is part of the US, a U.S. State the same as Florida, etc.

Comment: @L Walker Where are you actually resident? What are your ties to that country? What is the purpose of such lengthy repeated visits?

Answer (score 1):

The Visa Waiver Program allows ESTA holders to enter the US for tourism for up to 90 days per visit. There is no specific time period that you must stay out of the country, or any specific ratio of time spent inside vs outside.

Having said that, the immigration officer will make a determination when you present yourself at the border, whether to admit you under the VWP. They are not under any obligation to admit you just because you hold an ESTA, and they may refuse entry for any reason.

With your travel history, it doesn't seem like you would be trying to live within the US through frequent visits, so I don't see any reason why you would be refused entry. There are never any guarantees, of course.